# Convert a pybind11::object storing a long into a ssize_t

Tags: pybind11

I am defining a pybind11 method that takes an object argument type (because it can take a variety of different argument types). I want to check if that object is an integer, and if so get that integer. How do I do this?

In other words, what is the pybind11 equivalent of this python code:

```
def method(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, int):
        value = int(obj)
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

```
void method(const pybind11::object &obj) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

I've updated my answer based on [this issue](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1667) showing how to use templated functions.

You can use `py::cast` (see [the doc](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html?highlight=cast#casting-back-and-forth)) and use a `try catch` block to cast your `py::object` to int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

template <typename T>
void convert(const py::object stuf){
    try{
        T a = stuf.cast<T>();
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }catch(py::cast_error){
        std::cout << "Input object is not of known type\n";
    }
}

/* Wrapping routines with PyBind */
PYBIND11_MODULE(wrapper, m) {
        m.doc() = "";
        m.def("convert", &convert<int>, "");
        m.def("convert", &convert<float>, "");
        m.def("convert", &convert<double>, "");
        m.def("convert", &convert<bool>, "");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the `try catch`? Like a `can_cast` method that returns a bool?

Comment: not that I know of but maybe you can create a template function for that ?

Comment: I checked and there's a decent way to do this using templated function, I edited my answer with it.

Comment: That does hide the exception, but I was more worried about the performance penalty of generating one.

Comment: it doesn't really hide the exception as a different function will we called for each type, I am not sure I understand what performance penalty you mean?

Comment: Ah. The question asks for there to be one defined method exposed by the API, not several overloads. This is because pybind11 concatenates the docstrings when you define multiple methods, which makes them quite annoying to read.

Comment: Ooh I see, then I don't know of a solution just now, if I think of something I'll come back to you. Good luck!